# Normal casting vs bridge casting in Objective - C

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, ios4, xcode4.3

What is the different between,

```
(CFDataRef) data
```

&

```
(__bridge CFDataRef) data
```

Xcode asked me to change it to bridge. Is that because of ARC?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, ARC needs to be given instructions when you cast between toll-free bridged types. In this case `__bridge` tells ARC to do nothing, so this will behave the same as the previous standard cast.

You can read the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/index.html) for more details on the different ways to do bridging casts.