# Why do I need __bridge and what consequences does it have?

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Normal casting vs bridge casting in Objective - C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834522/normal-casting-vs-bridge-casting-in-objective-c)

With ARC, Xcode gently guides me to bridge cast my string to a `CFString` like this

```
MIDISourceCreate(theMidiClient, (__bridge CFStringRef)outName,
                 &midiOut);
```

1. What does this bridge mean?
2. Are there any consequences for memory management of doing this cast? Will the cast object be, um, cleaned up when it goes out of scope?

Comment: @JoshCaswell if you think it's really a dupe I'll delete, but I think my question is different. I'm not asking if it's due to ARC.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but CFStrings are not C strings, if by "C string" you mean a null-terminated array of chars.

Comment: @Monolo that's not a nitpick, but either fix it or tell me what to change it to, please.

Comment: I think that the answer there probably answers your question. I don't think you should necessarily remove your post.

Comment: @Yar you could just call it a `CFString`. The reason for my comment was that C strings, typically held in malloc'ed memory can't be passed to control under ARC with a simple cast - to my knowledge, at least.

Comment: Yeah, the link there explains it. See [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html), section Managing Toll-Free Bridging. __bridge says ownership is not transferred, so the CFStringRef will not have extra CFRelease called on it.

Comment: @PiotrKalinowski so this one line, as is, would cause a leak, right?

Comment: Nope. ARC will release outName somewhere. But if you want to 'retain' the converted pointer, you need to use __bridge_retained, otherwise ARC will insert release for outName, and when you later try to use the converted pointer, you'll get a reference to already freed memory.

Comment: @PiotrKalinowski thanks. That was my question, and it was not answered directly in the other question. Should this question get reoepened, you should make an answer with that.